# how to enforce method chained on a new line with eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want this:

```
const exists = await database.collection('products_info')
      .findOne({ date: LADate })
```

Become this:

```
const exists = await database
      .collection('products_info')
      .findOne({ date: LADate })
```

I have this on my `eslintrc`:

```
'newline-per-chained-call': ['error', { ignoreChainWithDepth: 1 }]
```

`ignoreChainWithDepth` does not accept less than 1

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I happened to be looking for the same, it seems to be a known bug: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12970, but because they've frozen stylistic rules and are no longer accepting changes, there's nothing to be done except write a plugin to handle it.

Comment: thanks for sharing, do you mean writing a plugin for the editor?

Comment: I mean an eslint plugin, a custom rule to replace the built-in but broken (even the docs show it working like we want, it just doesn't actually behave that way any more) one.